# How to obtain the complete parent taxonomy of an item on Wikidata using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, taxonomy, wikidata

I'm trying to pull the complete taxonomy of an item in Wikidata. For example:

With Snowflake Inc (Q22078063) I want to get all the classes that Snowflake Inc is an instance of and then trace those classes up. I don't care about any subclasses of the classes that Snowflake Inc is an instance of, but I need the complete view of what the parent classes are.

[Snowflake Inc (Q22078063)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcRlW.png)

I've tried several SPARQL queries, my most recent being this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?Class ?ClassLabel ?linkTo ?linkToLabel {
  wd:Q22078063 wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?Class.
  ?Class wdt:P279* ?linkTo.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
    }
```

I was attempting to use the subclass path to create a link between entities and ideally show a graph visual, but that does not work with this query.

Comment: what means "does not work"? I mean, please be more specific. So far the query returns a result and I can also switch to the Graph View in the Wikidata SPARQL UI

Comment: @UninformedUser the goal is to create a tree or graph that shows all of the classes that the entity is an instance of as well as all of the classes above the immediate classes. This query does not achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing is that the *first* part of your query will list all the classes in the hierarchy, i.e.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ?Class ?ClassLabel {
  wd:Q22078063 wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?Class.
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
    }
```

The issue with the query is in the second part, i.e. `?Class wdt:P279* ?linkTo.`.
This will flatten the hierarchy instead of preserving its structure.

A better query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?Class1 ?Class1Label ?Class2 ?Class2Label {
      wd:Q22078063 wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?Class1.
      ?Class1 wdt:P279 ?Class2
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
        }
```

You could also replace the head of the query with a `CONSTRUCT` statement, i.e.

```
CONSTRUCT {?Class1 wdt:P279 ?Class2}
....
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is incredibly helpful!